# ElasticSearch - Index a large file using Java API

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

We have a requirement wherein we have to use ElasticSearch for performing full text search. We have a Spring based application and for integration with ES we can use either Java API of Elastic Search or Spring Data for ElasticSearch.

The input will be of a file type having size around 5MB.

I went through examples for both ES Java API and SpringData, they do have
tutorials available for inserting a JSON document.

But any help with regards to using File as an input to create documents/index is not available.

I am newbie with Elastic Search, any guidance/help on this will be much appreciated.

EDIT:

I could see that there is a Ingest Attachment Processor plugin available in ES (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/ingest-attachment.html).

Can anybody point me to a sample CURL request to use this plugin or any Java code to use this plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.You may use **Elasticsearch mapper attachments plugin**. This plugin uses Apache Tika to ingest almost any well known type of document and make it searchable by Elasticsearch.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/mapper-attachments.html

2.You can use **Apache Tika**  to extract useful content from file and use elasticsearch Bulk Indexing api to index to ES

Hope that helps